# JQuery Input Class event catching doesn't work in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

First of all, I'm a Beginner in all the technologies I will talk about, but I need to setup a website to show my resaerch projects result, and I don't have the choice of the tech to use.

I have some issue running some Javascript / JQuery code within a ASP.NET MVC 5 website.

Here is what I want to integrate :

http://acanimal.github.io/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter02_03_layer_groups.html

This worked perfectly when I download the source, do some "Yeoman/Grunt/..." stuff, and open the html file.

Then I tried to include that within my ASP.NET Website. (I did some BundleConfig, etc...)

Almost every thing works fine, there is just the sliders event that does not work : I can slide then, but It seems the event is not "catched" and nothing happen.

Contrarly, the check box work perfectly and make the layers appears and disapears.

I was thinking that It my be because the slide is declared as an Input whit a class :

```
"<input ... class='opacity' type='text' value='' data-slider-min='0' data-slider-max='1' data-slider-step='0.1' data-slider-tooltip='hide'>";
```

and here is the event cacthing code :

```
 $('input.opacity').slider().on('slide', function(ev) {...do stuff...});
```

But I don't know what to do to correct this, and to be able to catch the sliding event

So if You have a solution, or if you think I don,t understand the problem, I'll be happy if you can tell me.

EDIT:

Here is the view (cshtml):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6nxjui2r96lgza/Index.cshtml?dl=0

EDIT2 : I just discover that it works in MVC with only one instance of the class.

```
<input type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="-20" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="-14" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="hide">
```

followed by

```
<input type="text" id="bar">
```

and the JQuery:

```
                   $('input.span2').slider().on('slide', function (ev) {
                $('#bar').val(ev.value);
            });
```

but not with more.

and it's work with many instance of the class in a simple html page. (I can ducplicate the input as I want, it cntinue to work)

Comment: Can you include the html/view code for context?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I restrart the project from zero, and import the exact same library that in the project example (nut using nuget this time), and it seems to works !